# Follow path object not following the path

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, constraints, path, axis

I added a camera with a constraint to follow a path, but when I slide the offset factor, the camera stays still and there is a blue dotted line moving from the camera to the position the camera should be. I tried many different Forward axis and Up axis combinations, nothing changed.

These are the follow path settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2qbx.png

Comment: well...up and forward axis y ...is wrong. If you provide blend file, i will check it out. If you don't want that, try playing around with that axis values.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-N6eNPurirh Here is the .blend file. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. apply scale + rotation to your path
2. set cam location + rotation to 0
3. set follow path like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome